# Mockito Issue with Long and Lombok

Tags: mockito, powermockito

How to write mockito for the below code, I went through: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-mockito-when-thenreturn-example/

Code:

```
@Override
public void saveEmployee(EmployeeDto dto) {
    Department department = getByDepartmentId(dto.getDepartmentId());
    RoleType roleType = getByRoleTypeId(dto.getRoleTypeId());

    Employee departmentMember = convertToEntity(dto, department, roleType);

    try {
        departmentMemberRepository.save(departmentMember);
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        throw new PCDataIntegrityViolationException("error");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new InternalServerException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "error", ex);
    }
}

private Employee convertToEntity(EmployeeDto dto, Department department, RoleType roleType) {
    return Employee.pmBuilder()
            .memberEmployeeId(dto.getMemberEmployeeId())
            .memberEmployeeName(dto.getMemberEmployeeName())
            .createUser(dto.getCreateUser())
            .lastUpdateUser(dto.getLastUpdateUser())
            .status(StatusEnum.get(dto.getStatus()))
            .department(department)
            .roleType(roleType)
            .build();
}

private Department getByDepartmentId(Long departmentId) {
    Optional<Department> optDepartment = departmentRepository.findById(departmentId);
    if(!optDepartment.isPresent()) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Error");
    }
    return optDepartment.get();
}

private RoleType getByRoleTypeId(Integer roleTypeId) {
    RoleType roleType = roleTypeRepository.findByRoleTypeId(roleTypeId);
    if(roleType == null) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("error");
    }
    return roleType;
}
```

I've written test class, only issue is that

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({AHUtils.class })
public class EmployeeServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeServiceimpl employeeServiceimpl;
    @Mock
    private Pageable pageable;
    @Mock
    private Page<Employee> employeePage;

    @Mock
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    @Mock
    private DepartmentRepository departmentRepositoryMock;

    @Mock
    private Employee employee;
    @Mock
    private Optional<Employee> employeeOptional;
    @Mock
    private Department departmentMock;
    @Mock
    private Optional<Department> departmentOptionalMock;
    @Mock
    private EmployeeDto employeeDto;
    @Mock
    private Sort sortMock;
    @Mock
    private Exception ex;
    @Mock
    private Environment env;

    @Test(expected = ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public void test_RoleTypeNotPresent() {
        when(departmentOptionalMock.get()).thenReturn(departmentMock);
        when(departmentOptionalMock.isPresent()).thenReturn(true);
        when(departmentRepositoryMock.findById(null)).thenReturn(departmentOptionalMock);
        doThrow(new ResourceNotFoundException("error")).when(employeeRepository).save(any());
        when(employeeDto.getDepartmentId()).thenReturn(null);
        employeeServiceimpl.saveEmployee(employeeDto);
    }
}
```

when `Optional<Department> optDepartment = departmentRepository.findById(departmentId);`, I wanted to have value in that so that I will go ahead, this testcase going inside if block.

Comment: What you do here looks like `overmocking`. You might want to restrict yourself to mock dependencies and use real objects where you can (for example the `Optionals`, `DTO`'s & `Exception`).

Comment: Please describe the behaviour you are experiencing and your expectations more clearly.

Comment: Although if I pass the 1L in DTO, by the time departmentRepository.findById(departmentId), mocking is not happening, its coming 0. I am not sure what you mean `overmocking` here. Could you please suggest?

Comment: Overmocking means you are replacing too many of the collaborating objects.  You should only mock the objects that have behavior that is difficult time/code-consuming to set up for a particular test condition.  You should mock as little as is needed to make your tests easy to write and understand.

Comment: See my answer below for an example. I still do not understand what your test is supposed to do, I'll added these inconsistencies below the example. What `0` are you referring to? So that might be related to the `deparmentId` (see a possible explanation for that in my answer as well).

Comment: I am saying that `Optional<Department> optDepartment = departmentRepository.findById(departmentId);` when this execute, I want mock object to be return, but somehow actual object (without hash coming) is coming. Did you got that now?

Comment: In that case, can you verify that the `departmentRepository` inside the instance of `EmployeeServiceimpl ` is actually a mocked object (and not the real instance)?

Comment: I added more details of how `@InjectMocks` works to my answer. In case you have verified that `departmentRepository` does not get injected, make sure to read that and adjust you code/tests accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In case your `DepartmentRepository` does not get injected into your `EmployeeServiceimpl` make sure of the following things
(Based on the [`javadoc of InjectMocks`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html)):

- In case you have at least one constructor with arguments:
  *(Mockito used constructor injection in that case)*
  All mocks that are supposed to be injected must be parameters of your constructor with the largest number of arguments.
  *Also note that mockito won't consider the other injection methods if there is a non no-args consturctor.*
- Second case would be you have setter method for the things you want to mock
  *(Mockito will use setter injection in that case)*
- In case you only have a no-args constructor and no setters:
  *(Mockito will use field injection in that case)*
  All mocks annotated with `@Mock` have to share the same name as the fields in your `EmployeeServiceimpl` class.

---

`Overmocking` generally refers to the fact you generate too much mocks, even for things that are not needed to be mocks.

You could change the first 3 lines to what the example belows shows.

Note that I changed the `.findById(null)` to `.findById(anyLong())`.
I am not sure what `getDepartmentId()` actually returns, for a primitive long you have to use `anyLong()` as a mock would return 0 (and not null) by default.

However in the example below I set the `departmentId` to `1L` so it should match regardless.

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({AHUtils.class })
public class EmployeeServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeServiceimpl employeeServiceimpl;

    @Mock
    private DepartmentRepository departmentRepositoryMock;

    @Test(expected = ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public void test_RoleTypeNotPresent() {

        Department department = new Department();
        department.setDepartmentId(1L);

        // only if you can't simply create that object, use the mock
        // Department department = Mockito.mock(Department.class);

        when(departmentRepositoryMock.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(department));

        // ... the rest of the example does not match with the code you posted ...

        employeeServiceimpl.saveEmployee(employeeDto);
    }
}
```

---

Note that the remaining part of your test,

```java
doThrow(new ResourceNotFoundException("error")).when(employeeRepository).save(any());
when(employeeDto.getDepartmentId()).thenReturn(null);
```

does not really match to the code you posted.
Instead your should define some behaviour on the mock of `roleTypeRepository`.

I am also not sure at what point a exception should be thrown, as there does not seem to be any interaction with an `employeeRepository`.